# How to change setTimeout number?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

lets say a website receives some data from users continuously. I want it to `alert()` users if it haven't received data from users in as long as 5 seconds.
  this is How I'm trying to do it:

```
countDown = 5000

if(//some data received from user){
  countDown = 5000
}

setTimeout(
    function() {
        alert('no data in 5 seconds')
    }, countDown);
}
```

well it's not working because It can't set *countDown* to 5 sec every time It receives data from users, So How can I do this?

and since the data from user comes continuously I guess it wouldn't be good for performance to run a new `setTimeout()` and destroy the old one every time.(?)

Comment: *I guess it wouldn't be good for performance* Really? Have you run a performance test to see? It's probably the best solution

Comment: Don't guess - figure out whether the performance loss would *really* be significant first. Odds are, it'll be quite imperceptible.

Comment: "*run a new setTimeout() and destroy the old*" - that's the way to go.

Comment: You could just use a seInterval instead, and then store a last accessed datetime, and then subtract from the current time.

Comment: @Keith That won't work as expected. Imagine user did something at `t = 1s`. The next test at `t = 5s` will pass. The test after is not untill `t = 10s`. So the user may have done nothing between `t = 1s` and `t = 10s` which is `9s`, yet no `alert` was shown.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir  you dont use a 5 second interval.

Answer (score 1):

This would be more of a recursive function that checks if there is any data. If not, it makes a function that runs in five seconds. If the data is still not there, you repeat the process.

```js
let countDown = 5000

function someFunction() {
  //this is called when you recieve data 
  timeoutFunc();
}

function timeoutFunc() {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      if (//still don't have new data) {
        alert('no data in 5 seconds');
        timeoutFunc();
      }
    }, countDown);
  } 
}
```

Comment: thanks, I actually end up doing a similar thing, but in your code there should be a `clearTimeout(//your time out name)` to clear old timeout (if there is any) then create new timeout. upvoted